# abp io error 404 on deploying in local iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, abp, abp.io

I am using abp.io community version for my project.
when i am trying to deploy my API to my local iis. I have some errors. development is working fine and good.

when i try to authorize with Client Id and Client Secret it shows me an [Error 404] ... See Pic 1.
[Error 404 Image and Right Side Login Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5z6Y.png)
on that screen there is a login button on the upper right side. when i click on that button it goes to login and authorizes me.

but that authorization is working only on get call not on post, put etc calls.

[i am using this architecture of abp.io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNDDU.png) . i dont have auth-server

[this is dbo.OpenIddictApplications Table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtMtw.png)

[this is the Api appsettings.json picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG1FR.png)

[this is the Db.Migrator appsetting.json picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMB4F.png)

Comment: By default, when the application is running, it generates logs. Check the logs of your running auth server when the 400 error is generated, it might give us some insights.